# ASP.NET MVC 4 Model is null after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, http-post

Hello this is my product controller i have one one table and one form in view. When I submit model. Product everything ok but when I return view from HttpPost Index model is always null.

If I reload page model is filled.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
     {
        var model = new ProductViewModel();
        var suppliers = new List<Supplier>();
        var categories = new List<GoodsCategory>();
        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            model.Products = session.Query<Product>().ToList();
            suppliers = (from d in session.Query<Supplier>()
                         select new Supplier
                             {
                                 Id = d.Id,
                                 Name = d.Name
                             }).ToList();

            categories = session.Query<GoodsCategory>().ToList();

            model.Suppliers = suppliers;
            model.Categories = session.Query<GoodsCategory>().ToList();
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        return View()
    }
```

Does anybody knows whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

type `return View(model);` in post action